# Unable to run Hello world

Tags: android, xml

I’m following a course about downloading android studio and how to set it up, I’ve downloaded the correct drivers for my cellphone but when I try to run my hello world program I have problems.

Keep in mind that the course itself adviced me to  update a file called activity_main.xml. This was the previous content of the file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.udacity.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This piece of code had to be updated to be consistent with the videos. New segment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.udacity.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to run the app on my phone here is what I get :

```
Error:(7, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘paddingBottom’ with value ‘@dimen/activity_vertical_margin’).
Error:(8, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘paddingLeft’ with value ‘@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin’).
Error:(9, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘paddingRight’ with value ‘@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin’).
Error:(10, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘paddingTop’ with value ‘@dimen/activity_vertical_margin’).
Error:Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDebugResources’.
```

Any help ?

Comment: in your @dimen file, do you have 
*<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">1dp</dimen>* ?

Answer (score 6):

Remove these lines from RelativeLayout:

```
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Or change the values:

```
 android:paddingBottom="16dp"
 android:paddingLeft="16dp"
 android:paddingRight="16dp"
 android:paddingTop="16dp"
```

`@dimen/...` are references to dimension values in the res/values/dimens.xml files. You probably do not have any values there and that's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

you have two ways:

One, create the resoureces like that:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Two set custom values like that:

```
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:paddingRight="10dp"
 android:paddingTop="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

With attributes like this, you refer to a `dimen` resource called `activity_horizontal_margin`:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

However, this dimension resource wasn't declared and the compiler fails.

You can fix thi by either creating the missing dimensions in the `res/values/dimens.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Or you hardcode the values like that:

```
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
```